# What is the usage of -F option in ln command on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ln

In https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ln, it says

```
       -F      If the target file already exists and is a directory, then remove
       it so that the link may occur.  The -F option should be used with
       either -f or -i options.  If neither -f nor -i is specified, -f is
       implied.  The -F option is a no-op unless -s is specified.
```

So how to use this option? If link a file to directory, a link with the same name will be created in that directory.

Comment: What if you create a symbolic link with `ln -sF file dir` where `dir` exists and is an empty directory?  Compare with not using `-F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, if the target file already exists and is a directory, then `ln` will remove it so that the link may occur.

```
mkdir dir1
echo hello >file
ln -s file dir1     # Creates a broken symlink at dir1/file pointing to itself

cat dir1/file
cat: dir1/file: Too many levels of symbolic links

mkdir dir2
echo hello >file
ln -Fs file dir2    # Removes dir1 and creates a symlink of dir1 pointing to file

cat dir2/file
cat: dir2/file: Not a directory

cat dir2
hello
```

Comment: And it works when relative path is used. ln -s <pathToFile> dir1 will not create a broken symlink